# SQLite - Using multiple mapping tables to resolve values

Tags: sql, join, sqlite, mapping

I have following database in **SQLite**:

I have a table (called keystrokes) containing keystroke combinations in English (has to be readable by humans). It has the following (example) structure:

```
---------------------
base | special1 | special2
---------------------
V      CTRL       ALT
F2     NONE       NONE
F4     ALT        NONE
```

The base field is a regular keyboard key and the special1 and special2 fields are "special" keyboard keys (Alt, Control, Shift, Windows, or none)

Then I have a mapping table (keymapping) to store internal key values that looks like this:

```
---------------------
key | keyvalue
---------------------
V     86
F2    133
F4    115
```

Lastly I have another table (keymappingspecial) that stores internal value for the special key, like this:

```
---------------------
key | keyvalue
---------------------
CTRL  1
ALT   2
NONE  0
```

I created seperate tables for the "regular" and "special" keys because the logic used in defining the numerical values is different.

Want I want is to be able to query both tables so that I translate the first table (keystrokes) to purely numerical values as defined in tables keymapping and keymappingspecial. 
The first example table would thus translate as follows:

```
---------------------
base | special1 | special2
---------------------
86     1          2
113    0          0
115    2          0
```

So far I've been unable to create a proper query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to just use a `JOIN` for this, joining on the `keymappingspecial` table twice:

```
SELECT km.KeyValue Base,
    kms.KeyValue Special1,
    kms2.KeyValue Special2
FROM keystrokes k
    INNER JOIN keymapping km ON k.base = km.key
    INNER JOIN keymappingspecial kms ON k.special1 = kms.key
    INNER JOIN keymappingspecial kms2 ON k.special2 = kms2.key
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/35520/1)

---

Another option is to use `MAX` with `CASE` to remove one of the Joins:

```
SELECT km.KeyValue Base,
    MAX(CASE WHEN kms.key = K.special1 THEN kms.KeyValue END) Special1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN kms.key = K.special2 THEN kms.KeyValue END) Special2
FROM keystrokes k
    INNER JOIN keymapping km ON k.base = km.key
    INNER JOIN keymappingspecial kms ON kms.key IN (k.special1,k.special2)
GROUP BY km.KeyValue
```

- [More Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/35520/3)

Comment: Thank you, both answers worked perfectly! I think I make in mistake while attempting to use a LEFT JOIN. Also, kudos for using SQL Fiddle!

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could use subqueries to look up the corresponding values:

```
SELECT (SELECT keyvalue
        FROM keymapping
        WHERE key = keystrokes.base) AS base,
       (SELECT keyvalue
        FROM keymappingspecial
        WHERE key = keystrokes.special1) AS special1,
       (SELECT keyvalue
        FROM keymappingspecial
        WHERE key = keystrokes.special2) AS special2
FROM keystrokes
```

However, not all databases can optimize subqueries as well as joins.
(SQLite will execute this query as fast as sgeddes' query with three joins.)

Comment: Thank you, this worked as well, though it's slightly less "clear" than using the INNER JOINs in my opinion.